# Move up, move down, specify position

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I know this should seem elementary, but for some reason I just can't wrap my head around the algorithm that would solve this problem, so I'm going to reach out to the community on this one.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class MapElementModel {
    int id;
    String name;
    int position;
    //other fields ommitted for space reasons

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now I'm storing the MapElementModel in a standard ArrayList. The user wants to move an element up in the list, down in the list, or specify a new position for the MapElementModel. The list is sorted based on MapElementModel.position.

So basically, if the user moves item 14 to position 3, that item needs to be inserted at position 3, the position field needs to change to 3 and all following positions need to change accordingly.

Likewise, a user could hit the "move up" button and move the item at position 9 to position 8. Again all remaining MapElementModel.position items needs to have their position field change accordingly.

Finally, a user could hit the "move down" button and move an item down in the list. Again all MapElementModel.position fields must be updated.

Does anyone have a good solution for this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Remove the `position` field, store all the elements in a `LinkedList` and use `add(int index, E element)` and `remove(int index)` to reflect user's actions?

Comment: Why don't you use a Map? Then you are not dependant on the indexing of a List, and all you have to do is update the keys (assuming Map<Integer, MapElementModel>) which would avoid reordering of the List constantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said, "The list is sorted based on MapElementModel.position", so my answer will be based off this. If it were sorted based on MapElementModel.id, this would be a different algorithm.

Think of the `ArrayList` as your ordered collection of items. Instead of "storing" the position in the MapElementModel, just let the index of the element in the `ArrayList` be its position. For example, if your `ArrayList` has the elements `["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "Purple"]`, then the position of "Red" is 0, the position of "Blue" is 1, and the position of "Green" is 2, and so on...

I'm assuming you don't care much about efficiency - i.e. you're not dealing with a list of 1 billion items.

Now, to move an item, our algorithm is to simply remove it from the list and insert it again at the correct location. Suppose we have the list again:

`["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "Purple"]`

Let's consider a few test cases:

- Move item at position 3 to position 0
- Move item at position 3 to position 5
- Move item at position 3 to position 3 (redundant case)

In the first case, we move "Yellow" to in front of "Red". So remove "Yellow" like this

```
String removed = list.remove( 3 );
```

Now we want to insert it back into position 0. It looks like we can just do

```
list.add( 0 , removed );
```

Simple, right? Remove element at given index, insert it at desired index. Let's see if it works for the second test case.

In case 2, we want to move "Yellow" to position 5. Notice that there are six elements in our list, and position 5 corresponds to the sixth position (if our array indexing starts at 0), so "Yellow" would go to the end of the list, after "Purple." So, we remove "Yellow" again:

```
String removed = list.remove( 3 );
```

But look now, everything after yellow has shifted down by 1:

```
["Red, "Blue", "Green", "Pink", "Purple"]
```

Conveniently, the index of "Purple" is 4, and if we insert at position 5 with

```
list.add( 5 , removed );
```

we get

```
["Red, "Blue", "Green", "Pink", "Purple"]
```

See if this algorithm works with putting yellow at position 3, the redundant case.

It looks like our algorithm works as follows: Remove at the given position, insert at the target position. It looks like we can just write an algorithm like this:

```
public void moveItem( int idxToMove , int targetIdx ) {
    String removed = list.remove( idxToMove );
    list.add( targetIdx , removed );
}
```

If the user wants to move the item at position 3 up 1 spot the list, you call

```
moveItem( 3 , 3+1 );
```

If the user wants to move the item at position 3 down 1 spot in the list, you call

```
moveItem( 3 , 3-1 );
```

What would you do if the user wants to move the item at position 0 down 1 spot in the list?

If the user wants to move item at position 5 to item at position 2, you call

```
moveItem( 5 , 2 );
```

Now you can implement this algorithm for an ArrayList of MapElementModel. If you really need the `position` field of your MapElementModel object to be correct, you simply go through the ArrayList and update it. The position of an element in the ArrayList is the element's position.

```
public void moveItem( int idxToMove , int targetIdx ) {
    //move the item as I did with Strings

    for ( int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++ ) {
        list.get( i ).position = i;
    }
}
```

If you need to move an item with a specified id, you would locate it in the ArrayList and then move it:

```
public void moveItemById( int itemId , int newPosition ) {
    int positionOfItem = -1;
    for ( int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++ ) {
        if ( list.get( i ).id == itemId ) {
            positionOfItem = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( positionOfItem != -1 ) {
        moveItem( positionOfItem , newPosition );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to abandon using an `ArrayList` to store them. Rather, consider using a `LinkedList`. A linked list is a very good data structure when you want to be swapping out objects and traversing the list by going from neighbor to neighbor. Removing an object, adding an object, or swapping two objects automatically updates all "indices" in that you do not have indices anymore, but rather only have your distance from the root item.

However, if you do want to stay with an ArrayList implementation, then yes you are correct. The problem that you are most likely coming up with is that you have to loop over the items that have to be changed and swap out the item at index `i` with say the item at index `i-1`. When you do this, you will be creating a lot of temporary objects in order to handle each swap.

Your code will look clunky and it will be slow (assuming you are doing a lot of swapping), but this is your penalty for using an ArrayList. The benefit is that you can access items directly by an index `i` without having to loop over `i` items in your LinkedList starting from your root object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement something *generic*? In this case i would use a LinkedList, but you can extend ArrayList instead.

```
public class MovableList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {

    public MovableList() {
        super();
    }

    public MovableList(Collection<T> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    /** Returns removed elements */
    public Collection<T> remove(int[] indexes) {
        Collection<T> removeList=new ArrayList(indexes.length);
        for(int index: indexes){
            removeList.add(get(index));
        }
        removeAll(removeList);
        return removeList;
    }

    /** Returns inserted elements */
    public Collection<T> insert(List<T> from, int[] indexes, int position) {
        Collection<T> insertList=new ArrayList(indexes.length);
        Arrays.sort(indexes);
        for(int index: indexes){
            insertList.add(from.get(index));
        }
        addAll(position, insertList);
        return insertList;
    }

    public void moveTo(int[] indexes, int position) {
        Arrays.sort(indexes);
        addAll(position, remove(indexes));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void shift(List<String> currentList, String element, int places) {
    int fromPos = -1;
    int toPos = 0; 

    if (places != 0) {

        //Creates a new list
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        // get curren position
        fromPos = currentList.indexOf(element);

        if (fromPos >= 0) {
            // If was found, calculates new position
            toPos = fromPos - places;               

            if (toPos >= 0 && toPos < currentList.size()) {
                // new position is in range

                if (places > 0) {
                    //move forward
                    if (toPos == 0) {
                        // move at the head
                        newList.offer(element);
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(0, fromPos));
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(fromPos + 1, currentList.size()));
                    } else {
                        // some places forward
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(0, toPos));
                        newList.offer(element);
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(toPos, fromPos));
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(fromPos + 1, currentList.size()));
                    }                       
                } else {
                    //move backward
                    if (toPos == (currentList.size() - 1)) {
                        // move at the end of the list
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(0, fromPos));
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(fromPos + 1, currentList.size()));
                        newList.offer(element);
                    } else {
                        // move some places backward
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(0, fromPos));
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(fromPos + 1, toPos + 1));
                        newList.offer(element);
                        newList.addAll(currentList.subList(toPos + 1, currentList.size()));
                    }                       
                }

                // replace old list
                currentList = newList;                      
                newList = null;                 

            }
        }           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is that you have redundant information that you're having to keep in sync. The "position" is stored in two places:

1. In the `List`, by virtue of which list element contains the object
2. In the `MapElementModel` itself, in the `position` field

You should consider getting rid of one of these, to avoid the need to keep them synchronised. Does an `MapElementModel` really need to know its own position in the list that contains it?

---

If you really have to keep both, you will need to:

- Remove the element from the list
- Insert the element in the new position
- Update the `position` field for the element with its new position
- Update the `position` field of any elements whose position has also been changed

So:

```
  // remove the element from the list
  oldPosition = element.getPosition();
  list.remove(oldPosition);

  // insert the element in its new position
  list.add(newPosition, element);

  // the elements with new positions are those with positions
  // greater than or equal to the new position or the old position,
  // whichever is lower

  for(int i = Math.min(newPosition,oldPosition); i<list.size(); i++) {
       list.get(i).setPosition(i);
  }
```

This is not especially efficient, but that's the limitation of the data structure you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a very expensive operation in an `ArrayList`. It requires shifting every element between the beginning of the list and the location of `C` down by one.

However, if you really want to do it:

```
int index = url.indexOf(itemToMove);
url.remove(index);
url.add(0, itemToMove);
```

If this is a frequent operation for you, and random access is rather less frequent, you might consider switching to another `List` implementation such as `LinkedList`. You should also consider whether a list is the right data structure at all if you're so concerned about the order of elements.

On the other hand if it's just to move a row only

Up:

```
int index = items.indexOf(myObject);
Collections.swap(items, index, Math.max (0, index - 1));
```

Donwn:

```
int index = items.indexOf(myObject);
Collections.swap(items, index, Math.min (items.size () - 1, index + 1));
```